# Manually specify which network interface to send data

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, boost-asio

I have implemented a service which sends and receives data over a tcp socket. Now there are two network interfaces on my machine, which I'm supposed to run the service over two networks.

How can I specify which network interface to send data? (Using Boost::asio or traditional Berkeley sockets, or by using a system call to change kernel's routing table on the fly)

Comment: What happens if you don't specify anything?

Comment: @egur The response for a request sent from a specific subnet, will be sent back to the wrong subnet.

Comment: this strongly hints to a wrong network configuration. Fix your network configuration and you won't need to specify that explicitly. Monkeypatching routing tables is btw. not an option due to the buffering of the kernel.

Comment: Sounds like a bad setup. What happens if you disable one of the adapter? Also, you should ask this on `super user` not stack overflow.

Comment: I don't understand it either.  Why does it matter which route is taken, as long as the data gets there?

Comment: @dom0 Not only the network config, also application architecture is nasty. Anyway, I've inherited this project and the only solution is to manually specify gateway.

Comment: @MartinJames I have two network interfaces (a wlan and a mobile network), each one getting data over its own listening socket, and should send requests on the same interface.

Comment: It may be helpful to add more details regarding the code, network configuration, system, and observed behavior in the question.  For what it is worth, I often find that its best to manage routing outside of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Boost, but in general if you want to send/recv using a specific interface than you need to `bind()` the socket to that interface's IP address, or alternatively on some platforms you can use `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE)` instead.

Comment: That will only receive connections from the specified address.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The **only** way to send/receive TCP data on a *specific* network is to bind the TCP socket to a *specific* NIC/interface. When making an outbound connection, you must call `bind()` or `setsockopt(SO_BINDTODEVICE)` before calling `connect()`. When accepting an inbound connection, it is automatically bound to whatever NIC/interface was used to accept it. You can `bind()`/`setsockopt(SO_BINDTODEVICE)` a listening socket to a specific NIC/interface, or you can just let it bind to all available NICs/interfaces and it will tell you which one accepted each connection.

Comment: I did not downvote, but `bind()` and `SO_BINDTODEVICE` are not synonymous.  When a socket `bind()`s to a specific address, the socket will only receive packets destined to that address and transmitted packets will use the address as their source address.  The kernel may still route packets through interfaces not associated with the address.  On the other hand, when a socket uses `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, any data sent to the socket will go out the associated interface and any  any data received through the socket is guaranteed to 
have arrived on the associated interface.

Comment: I mention both because Windows does not support `SO_BINDTODEVICE` so binding to an IP is also binding to a specific interface, but some other platforms do separate binding to IP vs binding to interface. So one may have to do both on platforms that support both.

Comment: I stressed the distinction because I interpreted the answer as suggesting that on platforms that support `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, one can either use `bind()` or `SO_BINDTODEVICE` and obtain the same result.  On Windows, binding to the IP will bind to an the associated interface, and the interface's `weakhostsend` configuration controls routing (defaulting to the behavior you describe on systems that support a strong host model when a socket binds to an address).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this, create a socket bind to 0.0.0.0 for receiving packet from all interfaces. Then create one socket for each interface for sending packet. Key thing here is to set REUSEADDRSS option so that socket for sending can bind to address per-interface and sharing the same port of the one receiving packet.

If you are dealing with TCP, an established connection will ready bind to a specific interface. You won't be able to send to that connection by other interfaces.